# How does .NET define a process architectural interface?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-5.0

I'm just curious how [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) defines a process architectural interface if I compile the source code under "Any CPU" configuration setting. I always thought that if you run that process in a x64 computer, it will be a 64-bit process. However, the example below shows a totally different thing.

I have a simple console program with code like this:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Process Type: {0}", Environment.Is64BitProcess?"64 Bit":"32 Bit" );

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

and the configuration setting is like this:

[image: Configuration Setting]

And my processor is 64 bit:

[image: Computer Processor]

Finally, the result shows

[image]

Could you please give some insights?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [this Microsoft blog post](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/04/04/what-anycpu-really-means-as-of-net-45-and-visual-studio-11/), which says:

> In .NET 4.5 and Visual Studio 11 the cheese has been moved. The default
> for most .NET projects is again AnyCPU, but there is more than one
> meaning to AnyCPU now. **There is an additional sub-type of AnyCPU, "Any
> CPU 32-bit preferred"**, which is the new default (overall, there are
> now five options for the /platform C# compiler switch: x86, Itanium,
> x64, anycpu, and anycpu32bitpreferred). When using that flavor of
> AnyCPU, the semantics are the following:
>
> - If the process runs on a 32-bit Windows system, it runs as a 32-bit
>   process. IL is compiled to x86 machine code.
> - If the process runs on a 64-bit Windows system, it runs as a 32-bit
>   process. IL is compiled to x86 machine code.
> - If the process runs on an ARM Windows system, it runs as a 32-bit process. IL is compiled to ARM machine code.

Turning "Prefer 32-bit" off will disable this behavior.

Comment: But what's the difference between `Any CPU 32-bit preferred` and `x86` then?

Comment: The difference between “Any CPU 32-bit preferred” and “x86” is:  A .NET application compiled to x86 will fail to run on an ARM Windows system, but an “Any CPU 32-bit preferred” application will run successfully.

Answer (score 4):

This would happen if you check Prefer 32-bit in the Build tab in Project Properties.

Comment: Your answer is correct also, however I can only accept one as the accepted answer. Sorry about that.